# Parsing an ASCII text file using GAWK

Tags: bash, shell, file, parsing, awk

I have been trying to parse an ASCII text file of the following format --

```
0 0 0x2de0 [0x98]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP -1/0: [0xffffffffc06ae000(0x5000) @ 0]: x /lib/modules/4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv4.ko

0x2e78 [0x90]: event: 1
.
. ... raw event: size 144 bytes
.  0000:  01 00 00 00 01 00 90 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0010:  00 30 6b c0 ff ff ff ff 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  .0k......P......
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  ......../lib/mod
.  0030:  75 6c 65 73 2f 34 2e 34 2e 30 2d 38 33 2d 67 65  ules/4.4.0-83-ge
.  0040:  6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 6e 65 74  neric/kernel/net
.  0050:  2f 69 70 76 34 2f 6e 65 74 66 69 6c 74 65 72 2f  /ipv4/netfilter/
.  0060:  69 70 74 5f 52 45 4a 45 43 54 2e 6b 6f 00 2e 6b  ipt_REJECT.ko..k
.  0070:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0080:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

0 0 0x2e78 [0x90]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP -1/0: [0xffffffffc06b3000(0x5000) @ 0]: x /lib/modules/4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_REJECT.ko

0x2f08 [0x88]: event: 1
.
. ... raw event: size 136 bytes
.  0000:  01 00 00 00 01 00 88 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0010:  00 80 6b c0 ff ff ff ff 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..k......P......
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  ......../lib/mod
.  0030:  75 6c 65 73 2f 34 2e 34 2e 30 2d 38 33 2d 67 65  ules/4.4.0-83-ge
.  0040:  6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 6e 65 74  neric/kernel/net
.  0050:  2f 6e 65 74 66 69 6c 74 65 72 2f 78 74 5f 74 63  /netfilter/xt_tc
.  0060:  70 75 64 70 2e 6b 6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  pudp.ko.........
.  0070:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0080:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                      

    ........[some other data]........
0x11590 [0x30]: PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE size: 0x2002a0  offset: 0  ref: 0x2d44e6441a3c2  idx: 0  tid: -1  cpu: 0
.
. ... Intel Processor Trace data: size 2097824 bytes
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)

.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
--- continued ---
```

The file will have several headers - as you can see in my snippet here.

`PERF_RECORD_MMAP` and `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE`

There will be other headers in the file as well.

What I want is that all the headers having `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` in my text file should only be considered. All the data following the `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` in my file should only be collected (i.e. all of the data starting with Intel Processor Trace Data). The `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` header also has a **size** field with the use of which I can specify how much of data is there to be collected within the `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` header.

**Edit #1** :

So basically, given the above input file snippet, I want the output to be of the following form (all the lines after record containing `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE`)...

```
.
. ... Intel Processor Trace data: size 2097824 bytes
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)

.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
--- continued ---
```

**EDIT #2** : This is another requirement that I have --

If I have an input snippet like below --

```
0 0 0x230 [0x60]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP -1/0: [0xffffffff81000000(0x3f000000) @ 0xffffffff81000000]: x [kernel.kallsyms]_text

0x290 [0x88]: event: 1
.
. ... raw event: size 136 bytes
.  0000:  01 00 00 00 01 00 88 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0010:  00 00 00 c0 ff ff ff ff 00 90 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  ......../lib/mod
.  0030:  75 6c 65 73 2f 34 2e 34 2e 30 2d 38 33 2d 67 65  ules/4.4.0-83-ge
.  0040:  6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72 69  neric/kernel/dri
.  0050:  76 65 72 73 2f 61 74 61 2f 6c 69 62 61 68 63 69  vers/ata/libahci
.  0060:  2e 6b 6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .ko.............
.  0070:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0080:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

0x11590 [0x30]: PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE size: 0x2002a0  offset: 0  ref: 0x2d44e6441a3c2  idx: 0  tid: -1  cpu: 0
.
. ... Intel Processor Trace data: size 2097824 bytes
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)
.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
.  00000036:  02 c8 c2 3a 7c 00 00 00                         VMCS 0x7c3ac2

0 0 0x290 [0x88]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP -1/0: [0xffffffffc0000000(0x9000) @ 0]: x /lib/modules/4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/drivers/ata/libahci.ko

0x318 [0x98]: event: 1
.
. ... raw event: size 152 bytes
.  0000:  01 00 00 00 01 00 98 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0010:  00 90 00 c0 ff ff ff ff 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  .........P......
.  0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  ......../lib/mod
.  0030:  75 6c 65 73 2f 34 2e 34 2e 30 2d 38 33 2d 67 65  ules/4.4.0-83-ge
.  0040:  6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72 69  neric/kernel/dri
.  0050:  76 65 72 73 2f 76 69 64 65 6f 2f 66 62 64 65 76  vers/video/fbdev
.  0060:  2f 63 6f 72 65 2f 66 62 5f 73 79 73 5f 66 6f 70  /core/fb_sys_fop
.  0070:  73 2e 6b 6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  s.ko............
.  0080:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
.  0090:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........


0x11590 [0x30]: PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE size: 0x2002a0  offset: 0  ref: 0x2d44e6441a3c2  idx: 0  tid: -1  cpu: 0
.
. ... Intel Processor Trace data: size 2097824 bytes
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)
.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
.  00000036:  02 c8 c2 3a 7c 00 00 00                         VMCS 0x7c3ac2
```

I only would need the data under the records containing `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` just like this. It would be great if the first line that contains

**Intel Processor Trace Data : size 2097824 bytes**

can also be avoided from my output.

```
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)
.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
.  00000000:  02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 02 82 PSB
.  00000010:  00 00 00                                        PAD
.  00000013:  99 20                                           MODE.TSX TXAbort:0 InTX:0
.  00000015:  99 01                                           MODE.Exec 64
.  00000017:  7d 08 45 06 81 ff ff 00                         FUP 0xffff81064508
.  0000001f:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            PAD
.  00000026:  02 43 00 76 49 1f 00 00                         PIP 0xfa4bb00 (NR=0)
.  0000002e:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         PAD
```

**Edit #3** : This is what I initially tried to do.. but which obviously does not work!

```
cat "$file" | gawk -F' ' -- '
  /PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE / {
    offset = strtonum($1)
    hsize  = strtonum(substr($2, 2))
    size   = strtonum($5)
    idx    = strtonum($11)
    ext    = ""


    ofile = sprintf("raw-pt.txt")
    begin = offset + hsize

    cmd = sprintf("dd if=%s of=%s conv=notrunc oflag=append ibs=1 " \
                  "count=%d status=none", file, ofile, size)

    #!cmd = sprintf("sed p")
    if (dry_run != 0) {
      print cmd
    }
    else {
     system(cmd)
    }
  }
```

I am not quite sure how can I properly parse this file to exactly get what I want. I also am not sure if using Python would help.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Still ambiguous, "all the lines after record containing PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE" ... until the end-of-file OR until the next start of a different section like PERF_RECORD_MMAP? Please clarify in the body of your Q, rather than in comments. I'll delete this if the Q is clear. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter, I have added more details to my question. I hope it becomes clear to you.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47564302/edit) and I'll retract my close vote. You've tagged your question `bash` and `awk`. I'd expect to see bash and awk code within your question.

Comment: Hi @ghoti, I have added my "not-working" awk code to my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you say you want from the input you posted is just:

```
awk 'f; /PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE/{f=1}' file
```

If that's not actually all you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide different sample input/output that more truly demonstrates your problem if necessary.

Comment: There's WAY too much text in your question now for me personally to read through it all to try to understand what you want. I don't understand why you can't simply show 1 sample of expected input and THE expected output given that input and concisely state your requirements. Maybe someone else will take the time to read through it all - good luck!